# Bundling and Minification .net mvc 3

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, bundle

I had successfully been able to bund my JS script and CSS style sheet on one file each using the bundling functionally offered by "system.web.optimization"

```
public static void RegisterBundler(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/CDN/Content/_LayoutNotAuth").Include("~/CDN/Content/style.css", "~/CDN/Content/select2.css", "~/CDN/Content/StyleUpdates.css", "~/CDN/Content/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css", "~/CDN/Content/jquery.qtip.min.css", "~/CDN/Content/htmlfeedback.css", "~/CDN/Content/facebookInputToken.css", "~/CDN/content/notifications/jquery.gritter.css"));
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/CDN/Scripts/_LayoutNotAuth").Include("~/CDN/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js", "~/CDN/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js", "~/CDN/Scripts/notifications.js", "~/CDN/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js", "~/CDN/Scripts/menu.js", "~/CDN/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js", "~/CDN/Scripts/Notifications/jquery.gritter.js", "~/CDN/Scripts/jquery.qtip.min.js", "~/CDN/Scripts/json2.min.js", "~/CDN/Scripts/jquery.signalR.min.js", "~/CDN/Scripts/jquery.validate.js", "~/CDN/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js", "~/CDN/Scripts/inputs.js", "~/CDN/Scripts/select2.js", "~/CDN/Scripts/jquery.simplemodal.1.4.2.min.js", "~/CDN/Scripts/htmlfeedback/html2canvas.js", "~/CDN/Scripts/htmlfeedback/jquery.htmlfeedback.js", "~/CDN/Scripts/jquery.blockUI.js", "~/CDN/Scripts/jquery.tokeninput.js", "~/CDN/Scripts/RechercheProjet/ProjectSearch.js", "~/CDN/Scripts/jquery.address-1.5.min.js", "~/CDN/Scripts/RechercheProjet/ContractorSearch.js", "~/CDN/Scripts/Contact/ProfileContact.js", "~/CDN/Scripts/RechercheProjet/resultats_recherche.js"));

        }
```

I’m wondering if I can automatically minify the resulting files using "system.web.optimization" .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable bundling and minification use this (this will disable optimization even if debug=true in web.config)

```
System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
```

If you put EnableOptimizations = true this will bundle and minify even if debug=true in web.config

Comment: I already add that to true, and the bundling is working, but when i use firebug to inspect the CSS (or JS ) resulting file, the file isn’t minified

Answer (score 1):

By default all files included in the Bundle would indeed be minified as well, but only in **Release** mode.

If you want to enable it in **Debug** mode as well, try adding this to your `RegisterBundle` method:

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

Comment: I already add that line, and the bundling is working, but when i use firebug  to inspect the CSS (or JS ) resulting file,  the file isn’t minified